# Load routes from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I want to load routes from a database table, instead of routes.php in codeigniter using HMVC framework? Any idea to achieve it without a hack in core Router.php file?

Comment: No, you have to hack Router.php.

Comment: in `routes.php` loop through your routes defined in db

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042099/database-driven-routing-in-codeigniter-2-x). There's also [a thread](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/121486) in CI forum.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need to load routes from the database?