# How to call one controller(function) view with multiple url in codeigniter via routes.

Tags: php, codeigniter

I create a controller function home/index .
calling vai url it is showing me html design.

I want to call the view of home/index via custom urls.

If I type

```
www.example.com/home_new  // it will open view of home/index

www.example.com/home_new1  // it will open view of home/index
```

Also i want to save the custum urls in database so that admin can change.

Please advise how to do this via routes or another method.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to inside route.php file:

```
$route['home_new'] = 'home/index';
$route['home_new1'] = 'home/index';
```

This will solve your problem. For database it will not help you.
You can take reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042099/database-driven-routing-in-codeigniter-2-x) link.

Comment: is it possible to add full link here like  $route['home_new'] = 'www.example.com/home/index';

Comment: @vipulsharma don't need to add full link. you have to set `base_url` in config.php as your `domain name`.